# Enumerate email accounts and list unread count on Windows Phone 7

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to create an application which lists all the users email configured accounts (Hotmail, Gmail, etc) and if possible the unread and "new unread" count. Clicking on one of these items will open the corresponding inbox.

Is this possible, and if so which class should I use? As far as I can tell it doesn't seem to be.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't currently supported : http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/84981/84981.aspx